# How to reference object without using property or ivar

Tags: objective-c, ios, object

If I use the following to add a UIView subclass in the subviews collection:

```
-(void)loadOutlet
{
    myOutlet *out = [[myOutlet alloc] init];
    [self addSubview:out];
    [out release];
}

-(void)unloadOutlet
{
    myOutlet *out = <<HOW CAN I REFERENCE IT FROM subviews array?>>
    [out removeFromSuperView];
}
```

Which is the best practice to do that?

Since now I'm using a loop for each subview finding with isKindOfClass, but there is not a better method?

Thanks.

Comment: Because I prefer to not declare properties that will be in memory while the view is loaded. In this case I have a few subviews that are loaded and unloaded during the master view life cycle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can assign a tag to the subview, then retrieve it using that same tag.

```
-(void)loadOutlet
{
    myOutlet *out = [[myOutlet alloc] init];
    out.tag = 1; // Or some other value
    [self addSubview:out];
    [out release];
}

-(void)unloadOutlet
{
    myOutlet *out = [self viewWithTag:1];
    [out removeFromSuperView];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively:

```
NSArray *currentSubViews = [self.subviews copy];

// Loop through each subview
for (id subview in currentSubViews) {

    // Check the Objective-C class of this object
    if ([subview isKindOfClass:[myOutlet class]]) {

        // Remove the superview
        [subview removeFromSuperView];
    }
}
```

The dynamic nature of Objective-C is a great tool.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, but as I've commented in the post, this is exactly the same method as I was being follow since now.